# Tomcat Servlet code equivalant for php's exit() or die()

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

Is there any way to make my servlet code to early exit, just like php's [exit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) or [die](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php)?

`System.exit()` will just stop the tomcat instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just `return` from the method.

```
public void doXxx(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // ...

    if (someCondition) {
        return;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for confirm this, there is no other options except controlling flow.

Comment: You can also put the "bottom" code in an `else` block or throw a `ServletException`.